# Goodness-of-fit test using Kolmogorov-Smirnov

Tags: r, distributions

I have a problem when I run the Komogorov-Smirnov test.

I have to samples of daily prices distributions estimated with density(). Now I would like to compare these two distributions with each other.

data.1:

```
Date           price
01.01.2010     1.2
02.01.2010     1.5
etc.
```

data.2:

```
Date           price
01.01.2009     0.1
02.01.2009     0.05
etc.
```

For the probability density, I calculated

```
density.1 <- density(data.1$price)
density.2 <- density(data.2$price)
```

Now I wanted to run the KS-test:

```
ks <- ks.test(density.1$x, density.2$x)
```

and got the results that p=1, hence the two distributions are the same. However, it is already observable from eye that they differ quite heavily from each other.

Where is my mistake?
Thank you, Dani

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you don't calculate the ks on an estimated density, as the ks test works on the empiric cumulative distribution function (ecdf). So you add the raw data:

```
ks.test(data.1$return, data.2$return)
```

Second, the `$x` is not the density, but the **uniformly distributed** grid constructed by the density function. So off course they are rather alike if the means are alike.

```
x <- rnorm(100,3)
y <- runif(100,min(x),max(x))
xx <- density(x)$x
yy <- density(y)$x
ks.test(xx,yy)
qqplot(xx,yy)
ks.test(x,y)
qqplot(x,y)
```

Last, please read in on a test if you use it before using it. Many mistakes in statistics are made by people that have no clue what they're actually doing. I don't say this to be rude, I just see things like this happen on an almost daily basis...

Answer (score 5):

ks.test receives **values**, not densities. So you don't need to call density().

Probably what you should do is simply:

```
ks.test(data.1$return, data.2$return)
```

and the reason why you get p=1 is that you passed `return.density.1$x` instead of `return.density.1$y`.
`density(foo)$x` is *the n coordinates of the points where the density is estimated.*